# glm::value_ptr has too many arguments

Tags: c++, glm-math

I'm new to OpenGL and GLM. I've been following online tutorials in hope of finding one that works. One tutorial tells me to use this snippet:

```
//Define the screen width and height, and get the ratio
const float S_WIDTH = 800;
const float S_HEIGHT = 600;
const float S_RATIO = S_WIDTH / S_HEIGHT;

//In my shader "shdprog" get the uniform variable "ortho"'s location
GLuint orthoadr = glGetUniformLocation(shdprog, "ortho");

//Create a 4x4 matrix using glm
glm::mat4 ortho = glm::ortho(-S_RATIO, S_RATIO, -1.f, 1.f, -1.f, 1.f);

//Set the custom GLSL "ortho" uniform to the value of the glm::mat4 ortho
glUniform4fv(orthoadr, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(ortho)/*too many arguments in function call*/);
```

For whatever reason, Visual Studio tells me that `glm::value_ptr()` has too many arguments("too many arguments in function call"). Even removing all the arguments causes nothing to change.

Is my tutorial in the wrong? Or did I mistype something?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE], along with the exact error message you get.

Comment: Sorry about that. Is this any better?

Comment: This isn't your problem, but `const float S_RATIO = S_WIDTH / S_HEIGHT` will yield a value of 1. You're doing *integer* math, which results in an integer, that then gets turned into a float. 800/600 is 1, when you round to the nearest integer.

Comment: Got it, I wasn't able to debug my code because of my trip I got right there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glUniform4fv` takes *three* parameters. The function you're clearly looking for is `glUniformMatrix4fv`, which takes four.